# Arrow alignment using CSS

Tags: css

I want to align the the arrow with line using CSS and Jquery.

I have a link of jfiddle. This is my code. I want to align the arrow with the line.This is arrow CSS:

```
.east {
    border-top: 5px solid #dcddd8;
    border-left: 5px solid #dcddd8;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/Abhinav015/u56qF/1/)

Comment: The line extending out to the right?

Comment: Yes .. the line extending to right must be aligned with that arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add arrow heads like the flowchart you sent me in the above comment you can add this to your css

```
.sep:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    border:6px solid;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #eee9dc;
    left:-70px;
    top:47px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xero1212/u56qF/6/

Comment: Could you please help me in this... i have posted but didn't got appropriate answer.Click here [StackoverFlow Question click here for info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795622/connect-divisions-with-line/20796305?noredirect=1#20796305)

Comment: You might want to look into SVG's. D3.js is a nice library for manipulating vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to your "east" class

```
position:absolute;
top:43px;
left:-80px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xero1212/u56qF/2/

Comment: No problem. Not sure why someone down voted your question. Have a good one.

Comment: Could you please help me in this... i have posted but didn't got appropriate answer. [StackoverFlow Question click here for info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795622/connect-divisions-with-line/20796305?noredirect=1#20796305)